# How do I custom draw a ComboBox item in dot net when suggest text is entered

Tags: events, combobox, autosuggest

```
AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
bound to DataTable
```

If I click the down arrow (to the right of the combobox), my custom .MeasureItem/.DrawItem fires for each item as needed.

What is the event called when you type into the text box, and windows does its thing to display the possible suggestions?